# iOS 13.5 Core Bluetooth - Scanning scanForPeripherals(withServices:) does not discover any peripheral

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I'm writing a very basic App that shall scan the environment for peripherals that provide a specific service and displays the device IDs and the RSSI in a table view. Nothing special.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
extension BLEScanner: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state {
        case .poweredOn:
            debug?.debug("Powered on")
            central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID(string: "FD6F")],
                                       options: [
                                        CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: false
                                       ])
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        let uuid = peripheral.identifier
        
        debug?.debug("UUID: \(uuid) \(peripheral.name) \(RSSI)")
    }
}
```

This code works as expected on devices running iOS12 and even on MacOSX, but when I run it on iOS13, no peripherals are being discovered.

I also tried other service UUIDs with the same result.

Isn't it possible to discover peripherals with specific services with iOS13 anymore?

Or could it be a device issue? I've installed iOS 13.5 on an iPad Pro (first generation), iOS13.6 on an iPhone 8 and iOS12.4 on an iPhone 6.

Comment: Try to restart bluetooth, I have this issue once. Doesn't device already connect to another iPhone while you trying scanForPeripherals(or maybe it's already connected in iPhone settings)? Also try to implement this connection logic: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH6-SW1

Comment: FD6F Is the exposure notification service. iOS will not let you discover that.  What other services did you try?  What if you specify `nil` for the services, do you discover anything?

Comment: I tried [1802,1811,1010], all simulated by the BLE Scanner App. When I set services no nil I see a lot of BLE devices around me but none of them offers any service. I tried to restart the iPhone, but still the same result.